# Formatting with par and justified option

Tags: formatting

I just learnt from [a vimcast (#18)](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/formatting-text-with-par/) that one can format paragraphs justified. This seemed very attractive to me, but I had one problem with it: I use double spaces after the end of sentences to distinguish periods from abbreviation dots. Using `set cpo+=J`, `par` does not preserve these double spaces; can it be made to?

Comment: Found this, not tried: `set formatprg=par\ 72q\ g1  " Use par for gq. use gw for internal formatting; g1 preserves double spaces after periods.` Source: http://www.8t8.us/configs/vimrc.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Not to let this without an answer; even if a short one)

A quick digging on the internet shows the right `par` option: `g1`. To quote the [source](http://www.8t8.us/configs/vimrc.txt):

```
set formatprg=par\ 72q\ g1  " Use par for gq. use gw for internal formatting
                            " g1 preserves double spaces after periods.
```